# Formatting UITableView Cells in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios-simulator, cell

I am developing an iphone app. In the image below I want the first name to be in plain font and the last name to be bold.. How can I do that? Please suggest me.. Please check this image:

[image]

Another questio..Now I think the reverse way but the problem here is the first line and second line you see are part of the same string. I want the first line to be bold and the second line to be in plain font. I am storing this in a dictionary. So my dictionary has a key and the value is a string of names and departments. I am unable to set the font. I tried to create two labels and tried to split the string according to the index and assign it to the labels I created. But, in this case the index keeps on changing as there might be a first name for a contact or there might not be any name.

In this case Prinicipal should be in plain font and name should be in bold

Please see the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Starting OS 6.0 there is a property on the UILabel called attributedText which has [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) type (Available in iOS 3.2 and later.).

Here it is how I am using it:

```
  NSDictionary  *firstNameAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0],
                                          NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]};
  NSDictionary  *lastNameAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0],
                                        NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]};
  NSString* first = ... first name ..;
  NSString* last = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",... last name ....];
  NSMutableAttributedString * name =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:first attributes:firstNameAttributes];
  NSMutableAttributedString * lastName =
  [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:last attributes:lastNameAttributes];
  [name appendAttributedString:lastName];

  [[cell textLabel] setAttributedText:name];
```

See also [Introduction to Attributed String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html).

Answer (score 5):

Since the label that you're showing the name string in defines the formatting and style, if you want to have different styles you need to have a different uilabel for each each style you want. Specifically, you will need a uilabel for the firstname: `firstNameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];` and one for the lastname: `lastNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];`. 
First place the first name string is the `firstNameLabel` then call `[firstNameLabel sizeToFit]` to fit the label text within it. Then use the frame of the `firstNameLabel` to place the `lastNameLabel` directly after it.

```
UILabel * firstNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,25)];
firstNameLabel.tag = firstNameLabelTag //This should be a constant probably
firstNameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
firstNameLabel.text = theStringRepresentingTheFirstName;
[firstNameLabel sizeToFit];

UILabel * lastNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(10+firstNameLabel.frame.size.width+2, 10, 100, 25)];
lastNameLabel.tag = lastNameLabelTag //This should be a constant probably
lastNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
lastNameLabel.text = theLastNameString;.

[cell.contentView addSubview:firstNameLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lastNameLabel];
```

And as for splitting the name string, you're probably pretty limited there. I would split on the first space and assume the first string is the last name (as in your first picture).

The principle case is similar, you need a label for each style that you want to present.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *title = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *plainText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ button pressed.", title];
    NSMutableAttributedString *styledText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:plainText];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.statusLabel.font.pointSize]};
    NSRange nameRange = [plainText rangeOfString:title];
    [styledText setAttributes:attributes range:nameRange];
    self.statusLabel.attributedText = styledText;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to create a custom `UITableViewCell`. http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/